# Scrapy images and save jpg

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am having some trouble scraping images.

**Settings.py:**

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.FilesPipeline': 1,
}
FILES_STORE = 'D:/0. Documentos/10. GitHub/0. 93Pipe/RealEstatePredictor/Images'
Items.py
```

**import scrapy**

```
class MagazineCover(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    pubDate = scrapy.Field()
    file_urls = scrapy.Field()
    files = scrapy.Field()
Scrapy spider:

imgs = response.css('div.gallery-content.item-gallery__wrapper  img::attr(src)').getall()
    

    for img in imgs:
        yield MagazineCover(title="title", pubDate="02/03/2021", file_urls=[img])
```

The spider read the URL, but the folder I set up in Settings.py is empty

**Outcome**

```
2021-02-04 15:24:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.portalinmobiliario.com/venta/departamento/conchali-metropolitana/6055529-julio-montt-salamanca-5935-uda>
{'file_urls': ['https://http2.mlstatic.com/julio-montt-salamanca-5935-D_NQ_NP_2X_760548-MLC44703096172_012021-R.jpg'],
 'pubDate': '02/03/2021',
 'title': 'title'}
```

**Thanks for your help!!**

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/66053830/939364, please remove one of the questions.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#enabling-your-media-pipeline):

For Images Pipeline, use:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}

IMAGES_STORE = '/path/to/valid/dir'
```

For Files Pipeline, use:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1}

FILES_STORE = '/path/to/valid/dir'
```

There is no `scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.FilesPipeline`.

Comment: Hi! I did what you mentioned, but I still don't get the folder "full" where scrapy supposed to save all the images. I don't know if I am missing something, appreciate it if you can help me!. Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure you have a correct directory name where you want to save images.
If you are on Windows here you have the correct files path format: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats.

You are using slashes "/" inside your path, but it looks like you need use backslashes "\"

Answer (score 0):

Three changes need to save image as per [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html)

```
1.For Images Pipeline, use:

    ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}

2.For the Images Pipeline, set the IMAGES_STORE setting:
    IMAGES_STORE = '/path/to/valid/dir'

3. In items.py 

class MagazineCover(scrapy.Item):
      image_urls = scrapy.Field()
```

and the end in your spider change this like

```
for img in imgs:
        yield MagazineCover(image_urls=[img])
```

Hope its help you.

Comment: Hi! I did what you mentioned, but I still don't get the folder "full" where scrapy supposed to save all the images. I don't know if I am missing something, appreciate it if you can help me!. Thanks!

Comment: I have successfully extracted images using these settings to provide  your solution. What's the problem are you facing now?